# Reset form to pristine state (AngularJS 1.0.x)

Tags: angularjs

A function to reset form fields to pristine state (reset dirty state) is on the roadmap for AngularJS 1.1.x. Unfortunately such a function is missing from the current stable release.

**What is the best way to reset all form fields to their initial pristine state for AngularJS 1.0.x.?**

I would like to know if this is fixable with a directive or other simple workaround. I prefer a solution without having to touch the original AngularJS sources. To clarify and demonstrate the problem, a link to JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/juurlink/FWGxG/7/

Desired feature is on the **Roadmap** - http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/angularjs-10-12-roadmap.html 
**Feature request** - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/856 
Proposed solution **Pull request** - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1127

### Updated with possible workaround

**Good enough workaround?**

I just figured out I can recompile the HTML part and put it back into the DOM. It works and it's fine for a temporarily solution, but also as @blesh mentioned in the comments:

*Controllers should be used for business logic only, not for DOM!*

```
<div id="myform">
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="form">
  </form>
</div>
```

And in my Controller on `resetForm()`:

- Save the original untouched HTML
- Recompile the saved original HTML
- Remove the current form from the DOM
- Insert the new compiled template into the DOM

The JavaScript:

```
var pristineFormTemplate = $('#myform').html();
$scope.resetForm = function () {
    $('#myform').empty().append($compile(pristineFormTemplate)($scope));
}
```

Comment: Protip: Controllers should be used for business logic only, not for DOM manipulation. DOM manipulation should happen via directives. [See "Using Controllers Correctly" here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller)

Comment: Indeed, it's a very smelly hack.

Comment: form.$setPristine() landed in [1.1.1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#111-pathological-kerning-2012-11-26)

Comment: With minimal effort, I simply copied the $setPristine() method and a few small dependencies (i.e., the `controls` array) from the 1.1.x branch. Works great.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Solution without a workaround

I came up with a solution which uses AngularJS without any workaround. The trick here is to use AngularJS ability to have more than one directive with the same name.

As others mentioned there is actually a pull request (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1127) which made it into the AngularJS 1.1.x branch which allows forms to be reset. The commit to this pull request  alters the ngModel and form/ngForm directives (I would have liked to add a link but Stackoverflow doesn't want me to add more than two links).

We can now define our own ngModel and form/ngForm directives and extend them with the functionality provided in the pull request.

I have wrapped these directives in a AngularJS module named resettableForm. All you have to do is to include this module to your project and your AngularJS version 1.0.x behaves as if it was an Angular 1.1.x version in this regard.

''Once you update to 1.1.x you don't even have to update your code, just remove the module and you are done!''

This module also passes all tests added to the 1.1.x branch for the form reset functionality.

You can see the module working in an example in a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jupiter/7jwZR/1/) I created.

### Step 1: Include the resettableform module in your project

```
(function(angular) {

// Copied from AngluarJS
function indexOf(array, obj) {
  if (array.indexOf) return array.indexOf(obj);

  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (obj === array[i]) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

// Copied from AngularJS
function arrayRemove(array, value) {
  var index = indexOf(array, value);
  if (index >=0)
    array.splice(index, 1);
  return value;
}

// Copied from AngularJS
var PRISTINE_CLASS = 'ng-pristine';
var DIRTY_CLASS = 'ng-dirty';

var formDirectiveFactory = function(isNgForm) {
    return function() {
        var formDirective = {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: ['form'],
            compile: function() {
                return {
                    pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                        var form = ctrls[0];
                        var $addControl = form.$addControl;
                        var $removeControl = form.$removeControl;
                        var controls = [];
                        form.$addControl = function(control) {
                            controls.push(control);
                            $addControl.apply(this, arguments);
                        }
                        form.$removeControl = function(control) {
                            arrayRemove(controls, control);
                            $removeControl.apply(this, arguments);
                        }
                        form.$setPristine = function() {
                            element.removeClass(DIRTY_CLASS).addClass(PRISTINE_CLASS);
                            form.$dirty = false;
                            form.$pristine = true;
                            angular.forEach(controls, function(control) {
                                control.$setPristine();
                            });
                        }
                    },
                };
            },
        };
        return isNgForm ? angular.extend(angular.copy(formDirective), {restrict: 'EAC'}) : formDirective;
    };
}
var ngFormDirective = formDirectiveFactory(true);
var formDirective = formDirectiveFactory();
angular.module('resettableForm', []).
    directive('ngForm', ngFormDirective).
    directive('form', formDirective).
    directive('ngModel', function() {
        return {
            require: ['ngModel'],
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                var control = ctrls[0];
                control.$setPristine = function() {
                    this.$dirty = false;
                    this.$pristine = true;
                    element.removeClass(DIRTY_CLASS).addClass(PRISTINE_CLASS);
                }
            },
        };
    });
})(angular);
```

### Step 2: Provide a method on your controller which resets the model

Please be aware that you must reset the model when you reset the form. In your controller you can write:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['resettableForm']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.form.$setPristine();
        $scope.model = '';
    };
}
```

### Step 3: Include this method in your HTML template

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form name="form">
    <input name="requiredField" ng-model="model.requiredField" required/> (Required, but no other validators)
    <p ng-show="form.requiredField.$errror.required">Field is required</p>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset form</button>
</form>
<p>Pristine: {{form.$pristine}}</p>
</div>
</dvi>
```

Comment: Elegant solution, works well. I like forwards-compatible fixes like this. Well done.

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much for you effort. I'm using AngularJS 1.0..7

Answer (score 86):

I think it's worth mentioning that in later versions of Angular (e.g. 1.1.5), you can call `$setPristine` on the form.

```
$scope.formName.$setPristine(true)
```

This will set all the form controls to pristine state as well.

[FormController.$setPristine](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController#$setPristine)

Comment: @bluehallu, where then should it be called? A directive's linking function?

Comment: Doesn't work: `Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined`. Actually, works when you put it inside a `$timeout(function () { ... });`, I guess it has to be asynchronous.

Comment: @bluehallu Yeah I would be curious to know too !

Answer (score 7):

EDIT... I'm removing my old answer, as it was not adequate.

I actually just ran into this issue myself and here was my solution: I made an extension method for angular. I did so by following a bit of what $scope.form.$setValidity() was doing (in reverse)...

**[Here's a plnkr demo of it in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0COYl)**

Here's the helper method I made. It's a hack, but it works:

```
angular.resetForm = function (scope, formName, defaults) {
    $('form[name=' + formName + '], form[name=' + formName + '] .ng-dirty').removeClass('ng-dirty').addClass('ng-pristine');
    var form = scope[formName];
    form.$dirty = false;
    form.$pristine = true;
    for(var field in form) {
      if(form[field].$pristine === false) {
        form[field].$pristine = true;
      }
      if(form[field].$dirty === true) {
        form[field].$dirty = false;
      }
    }
    for(var d in defaults) {
      scope[d] = defaults[d];
    }
};
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

Comment: Not quite yet. I use the $pristine/$dirty state to #1. Hide the initial required field messages per input element and #2 To test if the form is still in its initial state. The form is reused (without refreshing the page), so resetting the $pristine/$dirty state is important to detect changes.It's not solely for visual presentation, so I think I cannot solve this with style classes only.

Comment: Why would you not use form.element.$error.required and ngShow to show or hide the required field message? And a boolean on the scope to test to see if the form is in it's original state?

Comment: Also, have a look at this issue, it's an open request regarding what you're seeing: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/856

Comment: In the end, for now,  you're going to probably have to use a workaround.

Comment: Link to pull request for feature described: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1127

Comment: I've completely changed my answer, as I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your form fields should be linked to a variable within your $scope. You can reset the form by resetting the variables. It should probably be a single object like $scope.form.

Lets say you have a simple form for a user.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl($scope){
  var defaultForm = {
    first_name : "",
    last_name : "",
    address: "",
    email: ""
  };
  $scope.resetForm = function(){
    $scope.form = defaultForm;
  };
});
```

This will work great as long as your html looks like:

```
<form>
  <input ng-model="form.first_name"/>
  <input ng-model="form.last_name"/>
  <input ng-model="form.address"/>
  <input ng-model="form.email"/>
  <button ng-click="resetForm()">Reset Form</button>
</form>
```

Maybe I'm not understanding the issue here, so if this does not address your question, could you explain why exactly?

Comment: Added link to JSFiddle example to demonstrate the problem. Clearing inputs is not the problem. The problem is clearing the "pristine" state of the form fields.

Comment: Since `defaultForm` is an object reference, this might not work as expected.

Comment: Right, better you use: `$scope.form = angular.copy(defaultForm);`

Answer (score 2):

Here I have found a solution for putting the from to its pristine state.

```
var def = {
    name: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
    mobile: ''
};

$scope.submited = false;

$scope.regd = function (user) {
    if ($scope.user.$valid) {
        $http.post('saveUser', user).success(function (d) {
            angular.extend($scope.user, def);
            $scope.user.$setPristine(true);
            $scope.user.submited = false;
        }).error(function (e) {});
    } else {
        $scope.user.submited = true;
    }
};
```

Just write **[angular.extends(src,dst)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend)** ,so that your original object is just extends the blank object, which will appear as blank and rest all are default.

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

Using an external directive and a lot of jquery

```
app.controller('a', function($scope) {
    $scope.caca = function() {
        $scope.$emit('resetForm');
    }
});

app.directive('form', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, iElem) {
            scope.$on('resetForm', function() {
                iElem.find('[ng-model]').andSelf().add('[ng-form]').each(function(i, elem) {
                    var target = $(elem).addClass('ng-pristine').removeClass('ng-dirty');
                    var control = target.controller('ngModel') || target.controller('form');
                    control.$pristine = true;
                    control.$dirty = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pPbzz/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: just pass the form into the controller function. Below the form "myForm" is referenced by **this**, which is equivalent to $scope.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <ng-form name="myform">
        <input ng-model="mc.myFormValues.name" type="text" required>
        <button ng-click="mc.doSometing(this.myform)" type="submit" 
                ng-disabled="myform.$invalid||myform.$pristine">Do It!</button>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
function MyController(MyService) {
    var self = this;
    self.myFormValues = {
        name: 'Chris'
    };
    self.doSomething = function (form) {
        var aform = form;
        MyService.saveSomething(self.myFromValues)
            .then(function (result) {
                ...
                aform.$setPristine();
            }).catch(function (e) {
                ...
            aform.$setDirty();
        })
    }
}
```