# AngularJs empty form and remove invalid state from inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a form to add elements to list that is displayed on the side of the form. 
Markup is:

```
  <form name="thingForm">
      <input required type="text" ng-model="thing.name"/>
      <input required type="text" ng-model="thing.value"/>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="addThing(thing)"/>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="thing in things">{{thing.name}} with value of {{thing.value}}</li>
    </ul>
```

And in a controller I have:

```
$scope.things = [];
$scope.addThing = function(thing) {
    $scope.things.push(thing);
    $scope.thing = {};
};
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cXU2H/1/

Now as you can see, I can empty the form by emptying the model, however since the inputs have the required tag the browser still displays an error message (at least Chrome does).

I looked at the similar questions and:

- I've also looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296941/545925 however the jsfiddle behaves exactly the same as in my example: after the input is cleared it still has an `ng-invalid-required` class remaining (and it also triggers a HTML5 error message)
- <del>since I'm not on the 1.1.x branch `$setPristine()` is not available for me</del> `$setPristine()` behaves the same way

I can of course write a function that iterates through the elements of a form and removes every `ng-invalid-required` and `ng-invalid` class, but that is not the way I would like to solve this. That is what I would do with jQuery.

Comment: `$setPristine()` is the correct approach here. If you don't want to switch to 1.1.x just monkey-patch your version with this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/733a97adf87bf8f7ec6be22b37c4676cf7b5fc2b

Comment: Does the 1.1.x branch break anything in the 1.0.x version?

Comment: There is substantial number of changes in 1.1.x and there are breaking changes. Refer to the changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Okay, I tried the 1.1.5 version and $setPristine() behaves the same way. It empties the form but required inputs still trigger the HTML5 error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using $setPristine right? You can easily see in your fiddle that if you add it, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/X6brs/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.things = [];
    $scope.addThing = function(thing) {
        $scope.things.push(thing);
        $scope.thing = {};
        $scope.thingForm.$setPristine(true);
    };
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. In Chrome I get an HTML5 error saying "Please fill out this field" immediately after the input is cleared.

Comment: That's a different problem, after submission it is focusing the first invalid fields; either you change the input type to button instead of submit or do event.preventDefault() and handle the submission your way.

Comment: You are right. I added a preventDefault on the button and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Does this work for you? I am using Angular 1.2.13, and using `form.$setPristine(true)`, and I still have `ng-invalid` classes set on my field. I stepped through the angular source code, and it appears to do nothing to remove invalid classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.thingForm.$setPristine();
$scope.thingForm.$setUntouched();
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This did it for me, thank you very much! `$setPristine()` alone wasn't working.