# In AngularJS, what's the difference between ng-pristine and ng-dirty?

Tags: angularjs

What are the differences between `ng-pristine` and `ng-dirty`? It seems you can have both to be `true`:

```
$scope.myForm.$pristine = true; // after editing the form
```

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The `ng-dirty` class tells you that the form has been modified by the user, whereas the `ng-pristine` class tells you that the form has not been modified by the user. So `ng-dirty` and `ng-pristine` are two sides of the same story.

The classes are set on any field, while the form has two properties, `$dirty` and `$pristine`.

You can use the `$scope.form.$setPristine()` function to reset a form to pristine state (please note that this is an AngularJS 1.1.x feature).

If you want a `$scope.form.$setPristine()`-ish behavior even in 1.0.x branch of AngularJS, you need to roll your own solution (some pretty good ones can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603914/reset-form-to-pristine-state-angularjs-1-0-x)**). Basically, this means iterating over all form fields and setting their `$dirty` flag to `false`.

Comment: Good answer, but why 2 classes, if they are two sides of the same story? As I said, you can have both to be true or false.

Comment: That's right, but I guess (fear) that this is a question only the AngularJS devs can answer. In other words: I don't know.

Comment: @synergetic it is like the ng-show and ng-hide basically, one is enough but we have two for no visible reason

Comment: @synergetic ng-show is semantically more simple to understand, and requires one less cognitive step to comprehend than !ng-hide. your brain needs to do that extra step and thus you more likely to introduce bugs

Comment: I think it depends on your intent: Sometimes, you want to *show* additional things given a specific situation, and sometimes you need to *hide* some things given a specific situation. Depending on your use case, both may be appropriate. Of course, while it's technically the very same, intentionally it's not.

Answer (score 41):

pristine tells us if a field is still virgin, and dirty tells us if the user has already typed anything in the related field:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
  <input name="email" ng-model="data.email">
  <div class="info" ng-show="myForm.email.$pristine">
    Email is virgine.
  </div>
  <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty">
    E-mail is dirty
  </div>
</form>
```

A field that has registred a single keydown event is no more virgin (no more  pristine) and is therefore dirty for ever.

Comment: How about pasting with the mouse?

Comment: This does not explain anything. The question was 'what is the difference'. There is no explanation of what you mean by virgin and what you mean by dirty.

Answer (score 34):

Both directives obviously serve the same purpose, and though it seems that the decision of the angular team to include both interfere with the DRY principle and adds to the payload of the page, it still is rather practical to have them both around. It is easier to style your input elements as you have both .ng-pristine and .ng-dirty available for styling in your css files. I guess this was the primary reason for adding both directives.

Comment: +1 for the fact `.ng-pristine` and `.ng-dirty` allow different css styling - this seems the most correct reason behind the repitition

Answer (score 11):

As already stated in earlier answers, `ng-pristine` is for indicating that the field has not been modified, whereas `ng-dirty` is for telling it has been modified. Why need both?

Let's say we've got a form with phone and e-mail address among the fields. Either phone or e-mail is required, and you also have to notify the user when they've got invalid data in each field. This can be accomplished by using `ng-dirty` and `ng-pristine` together:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="email" ng-model="data.email" ng-required="!data.phone">
    <div class="error" 
         ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid && 
                  myForm.email.$pristine &&
                  myForm.phone.$pristine">Phone or e-mail required</div>
    <div class="error" 
         ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid && myForm.email.$dirty">
        E-mail is invalid
    </div>

    <input name="phone" ng-model="data.phone" ng-required="!data.email">
    <div class="error" 
         ng-show="myForm.phone.$invalid && 
                  myForm.email.$pristine &&
                  myForm.phone.$pristine">Phone or e-mail required</div>
    <div class="error" 
         ng-show="myForm.phone.$invalid && myForm.phone.$dirty">
        Phone is invalid
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**ng-pristine** *($pristine)*

Boolean True if the form/input has not been used yet (**not modified by the user**)

**ng-dirty** *($dirty)*

Boolean True if the form/input has been used (**modified by the user**)

---

**$setDirty();**
Sets the form to a dirty state.
This method can be called to add the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to a dirty state (ng-dirty class). This method will propagate current state to parent forms.

**$setPristine();**
Sets the form to its pristine state.
This method sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class. Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form.

*Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.*