# $dirty vs $invalid: What is the difference?

Tags: angularjs

I am a novice in angular. I am confused by `$dirty` and `$invalid`, they almost sound the same.

What is the difference between `$dirty` and `$invalid` used in `email` `ng-model`? Below is the `scenario`. It's an example form [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_validate).

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <p>
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
        <span style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="emaill" ng-model="email" required>
        <span style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="Count()"
            ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" title="Submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I am wondering if I change the ng-model name from `email` to `email8` it's not working anymore.

```
<input type="email" name="emaill" ng-model="email8" required>
```

Whether the validation is doing by `myForm` HTML element name which is not defined using `ng` attribute. How does it work?

```
ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid"
```

Comment: Dirty means it is touched already by the user. Invalid means when there is no valid input, i.e. a number instead of a letter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In AngularJS, what's the difference between ng-pristine and ng-dirty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073230/in-angularjs-whats-the-difference-between-ng-pristine-and-ng-dirty)

Comment: @ngLover Yeah should be closed. It's a question you can easily find the answer for.

Comment: @Mikey .. no it should not .. It's not ng-pristine vs ng-dirty

Comment: What determines if $invalid will be false? Where does it get set? What rules are used to set whether a field is valid?

Answer (score 12):

- `$dirty`: It will be TRUE, if the user has already interacted with the form.
- `$invalid`: It will be TRUE, if at least one containing form and control is invalid.

[Source](http://www.ng-vinod.com/2014/07/angularjs-pristine-dirty-valid-invalid.html)

[Also on Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

After the update in the Question...The validation is being done on the form element name. All the ng-models inside a form is tracked and that is how it is working.

Also changing a ng-model name will have no impact on validation. I tried your link and it works for me. That has to work.

Comment: I have updated my question .. can you please update your answer .. and one more thing .. can you please brief

Comment: I updated my answer after the update in your Question.

Comment: if ng-model name changed .. validation is not working(html input with no validation) .. which should not be .. because `myform.email.$dirty` accessing by html element name.. right??

Comment: It has nothing to do with the ng-model name change. I have tried with the same link and it works.

Comment: Jayram ... can you please explain the edit section question as well

Answer (score 2):

`$dirty` means the user has changed the input value, `$invalid` means the address itself is invalid. Therefore the error is only shown if the user has actively changed the input value to either an empty or invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

$dirty is True if user has already interacted with input. And $invalid is true if the the input is not a valid email address

Answer (score 1):

`$error` is the object of errors where the key is the field validation name and value is the actual error message

```
<input type="email" name="emailName" ng-model="email" required>
```

for this example `myForm.emailName.$error.email = true` if email is not matched with format.
`myForm.emailName.$error.required = true` if you haven't added anyhting in input field

you can check valid or not of the field directly by using `myForm.emailName.$valid` but
the problem in your case is they want to show the user what is the error by having two cases. so they entered into `$error object` to check for the `error is required email or invalid email`

```
1.Email is required.
2.Invalid email address.
```

so they used `$error` object.
this is how myForm.emailName looks:

```
{"$viewValue":"ss","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":false,"$touched":true,"$pristine":false,"$dirty":true,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"email":true},"$name":"emailName","$options":null}
```

I think the example provide by you explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake That is why it was not working , can you see below code which you have written

```
<pre>
<input type="email" name="emaill" ng-model="email8" required>
<ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
</pre>
```

Why it was not working because input name you have given "emaill" and in `myForm.email.$dirty` you have given "email" If both names should be same  then it will work fine

```
<pre>
<input type="email" name="emaill" ng-model="email8" required>
<ng-show="myForm.emaill.$dirty && myForm.emaill.$invalid"></pre>
```