# Clearing all inputs and restoring .ng-pristine on click

Tags: angularjs

It's still the first day of me using AngularJS after inheriting the project from a fellow developer. I was wondering, I have a login/registration form on my interface that is hidden once the items/form is submitted. Now once the user has submitted is there a correct or proper way to clear the form of it's entries and restore the .ng-pristine class on the items. The reason for this is should the user choose to log out and then login again (or another user wishes to register) the form is populated and has the validation css applied to it already. I don't want this, I would want everything to be empty and no CSS applied.

I can do this in JavaScript (obviously) however with AngularJS being a different approach I was wondering if I should approach this issue another way rather than loop through the form items and append a class to each item whilst clearing it's value.

This an example of one of my forms

```
<form name="signupForm" novalidate ng-submit="register(user)">
    <div><label for="email">email:</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required ng-model="user.email" ng-minlength=4></div>
    <div><label for="userName">Username:</label><input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" ng-model="user.userName" required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9 \-_.]*$/" ng-minlength=4></div>
    <div><label for="firstName">Vorname:</label><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" required  ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z \-_.]*$/" ng-minlength=3></div>
    <div><label for="lastName">Nachname:</label><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z \-_.]*$/" ng-minlength=4></div>
    <div><label for="password1">Passwort:</label><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" ng-model="user.password1" required ng-minlength=4></div>
    <div><label for="password2">Passwort wiederholen:</label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" ng-model="user.password2" valid-password2 ng-minlength=4 pw-check="password1"></div>

... and so on
```

Many thanks

Comment: use $setPristine() and clear the model manually in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to this post :

[Reset form to pristine state (AngularJS 1.0.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603914/reset-form-to-pristine-state-angularjs-1-0-x)

In the main question you got reference to issues and pull request on AngularJS. In resume you have to use $setPristine() method to your form.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

The form will appear in the correct scope under its name, i.e. `$scope.signupForm`. Additionally the object populating the form is `$scope.user`. In your controller, do:

```
$scope.user = {}; // or new User() if it is your case
$scope.signupForm.$setPristine();
```

In case `$scope.signupForm` is `undefined`, put a controller directly on the form, and place the code above (and anything else applicable) inside this new controller:

```
<form name="signupForm" novalidate ng-submit="register(user)"
    ng-controller="NewCtrl">
```

(This may happen due to scope nesting under your original controller.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('formController', function($scope, $document){
 
 $scope.Clear = function(){
 angular.forEach(angular.element($document[0].querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password]')), function (elem, index) {
 
 
            elem.value = '';
            /*
              Just extra do something
            
              
              
              elem.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error has-success');
            elem.parent().parent().children().find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-exclamation-sign glyphicon-ok');
              
              
            */
 
        });
        
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
        
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body ng-app="App">
      <div ng-controller="formController">
        <form name="myForm">
          <input type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="FN"/>             <br>
          <input type="text" name="LastName"/>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="UserName"/>
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="Password"/>
        </form>
        <button ng-click="Clear()">Clear</button>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Example, it worked for me i am using angularjs 1.6