# How do clear words/images upon form validation? (AngularJS)

Tags: image, angularjs, forms, validation, required

Just to be clear, in the subject line, it says "words/images". The "words" part is not about clearing the words in the form, but rather the word "required". As for images, these are validation images, like the green checkmark.

I just realized that I had no clue how to clear words/images upon form completion in AngularJS. Basically, the checkmark stays, and the word "required" appears after submitting the validated form. It does so, because now the form is empty. I tried using the $setPristine in the script page,

```
$scope.imgHolderComments.$setPristine(true);
```

knowing that it would probably not work. I looked for a workaround, so I checked out this impressive thread (but realized this was more for the validation itself and not added words/images).

[Reset form to pristine state (AngularJS 1.0.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603914/reset-form-to-pristine-state-angularjs-1-0-x)

Then I tried using this code which I had used prior to today for the pre-validation. Or if you will, for the live validation, before submitting the form. I thought I could recycle this, but no.

```
$scope.checkUrl = 'images/validation/y_square_trans.png';
            $scope.loadUrl = 'images/validation/loading.gif';
            $scope.crossUrl = 'images/validation/loading_wrong.gif';
            $scope.imgHolderComments = '';
            $scope.comments = "";
            $scope.timeout = null;
            $scope.imgHolderComments = ($scope.reviewForm.comments.$invalid) ? $scope.crossUrl : $scope.crossUrl;
```

That looked so dirty, but thought it could work after pushing the data in. But the image stayed there (as you can see, I tried replacing the checkmark with a cross instead, as I did not want to create a blank pic).

I also googled it, but everything I could find had to do with two things: clearing the form AND removing the coloured frame (red/green). of course, my form already does that. So, I'm still trying to find a way to remove the word "required" and the gif image in my form upon successful validation.

In any case, I created a plunker. You'll have to click on the word "Reviews" to show the form.

http://embed.plnkr.co/QZT1Jzgg9elMMRHwhYel/preview

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the directives `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

You can set `$scope.allGood = true;` somewhere in your controller (after validation) and use this directive: `<span ng-hide="allGood">Required</span>`

**Edit:**
You might also want to look at the `ng-class` directive. Example:
`<span ng-class="{green: allGood == 1}">Name:</span>` and obviously style the class `green` to your needs.

Comment: Well, I basically used this in every form question. Would this be considered 'wrong' the way I used it?: ng-click="requiredBlank=''" And used this in the submit button: ng-click="submitted=true requiredBlank='displayNone'"

Comment: In case the validation happens globally and not per field, you could also just add the `ng-class` as per my example to the form itself instead of its fields. And hide the required labels with CSS, in one go. Not sure if this applies – feel free to update your plunker so I can look at what it looks like now.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, weekends equals more home responsibilities lol. What I modded is not working anymore (maybe my cache had messed up anything before I cleared it. Cleared it again to make sure). I don't know why, but I was trying to imitate some things you were speaking about. I can show you. http://embed.plnkr.co/NOwlKwCQNL5weH53jd4D/preview